# How to configure SSO to SAP Fiori application in an MS Teams Personal app

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I'm wondering how to implement SSO in an MS Teams Personal Tab, which points to a SAP Fiori app / page.

The fiori app is SSO enabled through Azure AD SAML authentication.

When loading the Fiori app in the Personal Tab right now, there is a redirect to https://login.microsoftonline.com/... , which can't be loaded due to an `X-Frame-Options: DENY` header.
This effectively blocks authentication to the app.

In the [SSO for Teams Apps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso) it's not clear to me if the authentication can be passed through to the loaded application rather than retrieving tokes from the JS api and passing them on as a Bearer token.

So my question: is there a way to pass authentication to a secured application, rather than requesting tokens from the JS API?

Comment: If you want to pass authentication to a secured application, the application or page should be iFramable. Teams does not allow the application or page without iFrame and if you don't have iFrame option in your application use JS token API. Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements#:~:text=Teams%20tabs%20must%20adhere%20to,Security%2DPolicy%20HTTP%20response%20headers.&text=For%20Internet%20Explorer%2011%20compatibility,%2DSecurity%2DPolicy%20as%20well.).

Comment: @Mamatha-MSFT `login.microsoftonline.com` is obviously not under my control. Does this mean AAD SAML auth in an MS Teams app is simply not supported?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass authentication to a secured application, the application or page should be iFramable. Teams does not allow the application or page without iFrame and if you don't have iFrame option in your application use JS token API. Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements#:%7E:text=Teams%20tabs%20must%20adhere%20to,Security%2DPolicy%20HTTP%20response%20headers.&text=For%20Internet%20Explorer%2011%20compatibility,%2DSecurity%2DPolicy%20as%20well.).

For SSO you need to get authentication token, you need to call getAuthtoken() function. Currently only way to get a token is via JS SDK and currently SAML auth is not supported only OAuth SSO is supported.